# Which is the best way to Send/Load an immense 200MB image in my webapp?

Tags: node.js, web, blazor

I'm trying to send images between websockets, but it is not working with large images. I have a webapp (Blazor webAsembly) that receives images from a Node.js server, the problem appears when I want to send images that are so much larger and the socket collapses. I want to send that are immense files between my server and my client to show on the web.

The loop, the image is sent as Base64:

```
        private async Task Echo(WebSocket webSocketClient)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[1024 * 250000];

            do
            {
                var receiveResult = await webSocketClient.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
                //string messageFromServer;
                //messageFromServer = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, receiveResult.Count);
                onMessage(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, receiveResult.Count));
                await webSocketClient.SendAsync(
                    new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, receiveResult.Count),
                    receiveResult.MessageType,
                    receiveResult.EndOfMessage,
                    CancellationToken.None);
            } while (true);
        }
```

My error:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: An internal WebSocket error occurred. Please see the innerException, if present, for more details. 
System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (0x80004005): An internal WebSocket error occurred. Please see the innerException, if present, for more details. 
 ---> System.OutOfMemoryException: Out of memory
```

Comment: What do you mean with "shocket collapse"? What is the actual thing that happens? How are you sending that data? (Can you show us the code that's not working, on both the Node.js and the client side?)

Comment: Don't use websockets for uploads.

Comment: @robertklep yes ik but wich is the way ?

Comment: @robertklep Why couldn't you use websockets for uploads?

Comment: @AKX I updated the post now u can see everithing

Comment: "the image is sended as Base64" – why? Websockets are perfectly able to send binary data, and encoding as base64 makes the data approx. 33% larger than the original.

Comment: @AKX i was in a hurry and that was a fast way. now i have more time and im improveing that

Comment: Well, I would expect your client not to run out of memory that easily if it didn't need to assemble the full 200*1.33 megs first and decode it. Maybe do that, and then see if you still have an issue.

Comment: @AKX im not much sure what u mean to do.

Comment: What does that `onMessage` function do? In any case, you're (a) receiving a big blob of binary data (b) decoding that to a string (c) then doing something else...

Comment: @AKX yes thats exactly what i do,,onMessage s an event tha sends the own messge to the front end